# Conditional formatting derived from formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

In cell `D11`, I have a date derived from a formula. `(IF&Vlookup)`

I have tried to insert a basic conditional formatting to highlight D11 if the date is before today's date. The format of cell D11 is `date`. 
The conditional formatting works if I type in the date but won't if it is derived from a formula.

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(VLOOKUP($D$10,'Lookup data'!G6:I52,3,FALSE),"dd/mm/yyyy"),"  " )
```

The conditonal formatting formula is:

```
=D11>TODAY()
```

Comment: Would like to know what is the formula that returns the date? and what is the CF formula that you use. Please add that to the question

Comment: I just added it. Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly need to make that lookup array into an absolute reference, as otherwise I think CF is like everywhere else in that the array will shift as the cell being formatted does.

Comment: @Abigal What about the conditional formatting formula?

Comment: added the conditonal formatting formula too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your formula to:

```
=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(VLOOKUP($D$10,'Lookup Data'!$G$6:$I$52,3,FALSE),"dd/mm/yyyy")),"")
```

For conditional Formatting use:

```
=AND(D11>TODAY(),D11<>"")
```

and format as you like

Like Gotham said the Text() formula convert your date in Vlookup to Text that you cannot compare to Today() date
One is text and the other is Date
The new formula use Datevalue to convert Text() to Date and " "  iferror to just "" empty.
D11 if empty or "" result iferror should not format the cell, that is why I changed the Conditional Formatting Formula

Comment: Thank you Yass and all. This does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

The CF formula `=D11>TODAY()` is supposed to compare a date with another date.

The `D11` should be a date, (not formatted as a date with TEXT `function`). The TEXT function represents the date in that format `dd/mm/yyyy`, but it is still a text and cannot be compared with a date

You may have to use the `DATE` function in your `VLOOKUP` instead. Of format the lookup table with date format. Try it out and let us know if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: The lookup data table is already formatted as date. I am not sure what you mean by "You may have to use the DATE function in your VLOOKUP instead"

Comment: @Abigal If the lookup table is already formatted as a date, then no need of the `TEXT` function in your formula.